# Setting state and filtering.skipping data - React / Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm setting my state value like this:

```
this.setState({
  products: response.data.data.map(product => {
  return { key: product.id, value: product.productName };
    }),
});
```

But I want to get rid of products who has type different that 2

I've tried something like this:

```
this.setState({
  products: response.data.data.map(product => {
  return { key: product.id, value: product.productName };
    }).find(x => x.productType != 2),
});
```

But this didn't work.. I'm wondering how could I do it here (Avoid data which I don't want and set state value as that).

Comment: `let data = { numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4] }; data.numbers.filter((i) => { if (i !== 2) { return i } });` try something like that. To give you an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter()`, like this:

```
const shouldFilter = true; // should we filter out unwanted values or keep all of them?
this.setState({
  products: response.data.data
    .filter(product => shouldFilter ? product.productType === 2 : true) // return only products with type === 2 if shouldFilter is true
    .map(product => {
      return { key: product.id, value: product.productName };
    })
});
```

Which first filters the array, and then maps to the desired values

Comment: is it possible to add if condition somewhere there for example `if(something)` than do that filtering part..

Comment: Sure, see my updated answer. If `shouldFilter` will be set to `true`, then only products with type 2 will be included. Otherwise, all of the will be kept

Answer (score 0):

consider the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component { 

state = {
  products: []
};  

constructor(){
  super();
  this.items = this.state.products.map((item, key) =>
    <li key={item.id}>{item.value}</li>
);
}




componentDidMount(){

  var responseData = [{key: 1, value: "CocaCola", type: "1" },{key: 1, value: "PepsiCola", type: "2"}, {key: 1, value: "Snickers", type: "1"},
   {key: 3, value: "Marshmallow", type: "2"},{key: 4, value: "Lolipop", type: "2"}];   


  var selectedProducts = responseData.filter(product => product.type !== "2"); 
   this.setState({products: selectedProducts}); 


}



  render() { 

    const items = this.state.products.map((item, key) =>
        <li key={item.id}>{item.value}</li>
    );

    return <ul>{items}</ul>
  };
}
export default App;
```

Here, we have responseData array with objects describing the products. 
In order to cut off some objects from an array of objects, you need to use the array method called filter(). This method takes a function as an argument, in our case this function iterates over all objects in the array, taking each as product and then returning only those products, where product.type is not equal to "2". Then we set(replace) the state property "products" value with that of the filtered array. 
In order to show the resulting array to the user, in the constructor method we then create this.items to hold an array of JSX list-items, which we then render to the DOM in render() method.